# C++ VS2017 compiler error with struct stat from wchar.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to use the structure `struct stat` in my code from `#include<wchar.h>` but it is failing to compile, stating

> int(const char *const, stat *const); illegal sizeof operand.

Clearly compiler cannot see the definition of `struct stat` which I see is defined inside `#include<wchar.h>` within macro block `#if !__STDC__`.

Question, how to make my code visible to the definition of `struct stat`?

Comment: `int foo(const char *const, struct stat *const);` works for me. Without `struct stat` it is finding the `stat` function. That is with VS2019 though. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: SInce you tagged the question c++, try including the C++ version of the header `#include <cwchar>`.